# Switching between 2 divs with 2 buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to switch between 2 divs with 2 buttons. I've went all over google but still nothing. Could you please tell me where I'm wrong, I'm sure it's in the jQuery. Also is it possible to use normal  instead of ?

Here is my code:

```js
// only show one panel at a time
jQuery(".flip").on("click", function(e) {
  var target = jQuery(this).attr("href");
  jQuery(target).slideToggle("fast");
  jQuery(".content").not(target).hide();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.button-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.button-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin: 10px
}

.content h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <a class="flip top-button" href="#first-div" target="" data-toggle="">Div1</a>
    <a class="flip top-button" href="#second-div" target="" data-toggle="">Div2</a>
  </div>

  <div class="content" id="cont1">
    <h1>Im the first DIV</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="cont2">
    <h1>Im the second DIV</h1>
  </div>
```

Here is a codepen also:

https://codepen.io/Sarithan/pen/Wywmrx

Comment: Please define "switch between 2 divs with 2 buttons". Do you want to hide the appropriate div when you click on a button? Do you want to swap their positions?

Comment: I want to be able to switch between 2 divs and have 2 buttons. When you click on button 1 to show only the first div and when you click on button 2 only the 2nd div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. You need to change the `Id` of `div` to `href` of `flip`. Your code didn't work because you have different `id` in `href` of your `.flip` element then in your `.content` element.

```js
// only show one panel at a time
jQuery(".flip").on("click", function(e) {        
    var target = jQuery(this).attr("href");
    jQuery(target).slideToggle("fast");
    jQuery(".content").not(target).hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.button-wrapper{
  text-align: center;
}

.button-wrapper a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin: 10px
}

.content h1{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.top-button{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 5rem;
    margin: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12;
    -moz-border-radius: 12;
    border-radius: 4px;
} 

.top-button a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button-wrapper">
   <a class="flip top-button" href="#first-div" target="" data-toggle="">Div1</a>
   <a class="flip top-button" href="#second-div" target="" data-toggle="">Div2</a>
   </div>

  <div class="content" id="first-div">
       <h1>Im the first DIV</h1>
  </div>
   <div class="content" id="second-div" style="display:none">
       <h1>Im the second DIV</h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your answer works in the code snippet and in codepen, but it doesn't work in my editor.. ;/

Comment: @PeterBrezitski do you have exact same code on your text editor?

Comment: @PeterBrezitski Then there might be some error in you console. Is there any error?

Comment: No errors. 

This is the jQuery code i paste in the head tag:

Comment: // only show one panel at a time
          jQuery(".flip").on("click", function(e) {        
                var target = jQuery(this).attr("href");
                jQuery(target).slideToggle("fast");
                jQuery(".content").not(target).hide();
                e.preventDefault();
            });

Comment: No matter where you add this code. Just you need this code executed after jQuery. It need to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to replace the id of the `.content` element to be equal to the value of the `href` of `.flip` but of course without the `#`

Plus, change `slideToggle` in your javascript to `show` so that the first time you click on the div it will keep showing

```js
// only show one panel at a time
jQuery(".flip").on("click", function(e) {
  var target = jQuery(this).attr("href");
  jQuery(target).show("fast");
  jQuery(".content").not(target).hide();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.button-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.button-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin: 10px
}

.content h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <a class="flip top-button" href="#first-div" target="" data-toggle="">Div1</a>
    <a class="flip top-button" href="#second-div" target="" data-toggle="">Div2</a>
  </div>

  <div class="content" id="first-div">
    <h1>Im the first DIV</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="second-div">
    <h1>Im the second DIV</h1>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Make your button `href` to same as the `id` of the content. So there will be a link to determine which `content` should be shown on the button click. Hide all the content class on css. And trigger `click` event in the code. So that on page load it will display the content. Only thing you have to do is to switch the view

```js
$(".flip").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".content").hide();
    $($(this).attr("href")).show("fast");    
});
$("a[href='#first-div']").trigger('click');
```

```css
.button-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.button-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin: 10px
}

.content h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
.content{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button-wrapper">
   <a class="flip top-button" href="#first-div" target="" data-toggle="">Div1</a>
   <a class="flip top-button" href="#second-div" target="" data-toggle="">Div2</a>
   </div>

  <div class="content" id="first-div">
       <h1>Im the first DIV</h1>
  </div>
   <div class="content" id="second-div">
       <h1>Im the second DIV</h1>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As i see in code the problem is not in jQuery, it is in html as you hide div based on id of the div but the div id (cont1, cont2) is given as different in href tag so it is must be same.

```js
// only show one panel at a time
jQuery(".flip").on("click", function(e) {
  var target = jQuery(this).attr("href");
  jQuery(target).slideToggle("fast");
  jQuery(".content").not(target).hide();
  e.preventDefault();
});

$('#first-div').hide();
$('#second-div').hide();
```

```css
.button-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.button-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin: 10px
}

.content h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <a class="flip top-button" href="#first-div" target="" data-toggle="">Div1</a>
    <a class="flip top-button" href="#second-div" target="" data-toggle="">Div2</a>
  </div>

  <div class="content" id="first-div">
    <h1>Im the first DIV</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="second-div">
    <h1>Im the second DIV</h1>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use regular JavaScript!
I don't understand why everybody used jQuery here.

Here is my solution, where I:

- Added a `class="height0"` and some styling,
- Changed your `a` buttons to `span` buttons, so you don't have to use `.preventDefault()` and additional styling.

```js
// Using only JavaScript
var flips = document.querySelectorAll(".flip");
var contents = document.querySelectorAll(".content");
flips.forEach(function(flip) {
  flip.onclick = function() {
    // Hide all
    contents.forEach(function(content) {
      content.classList.add('height0');
    })
    // Show only the one you want
    // (With a timeout, but that's not mandatory!)
    setTimeout(function() {
      var target = flip.getAttribute("target");
      document.querySelector(target).classList.remove('height0');
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```css
.button-wrapper {
  margin: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1em; /* <-- Reduced here, for tiny snippet */
}

.top-button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 5rem;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Added the below */

.content {
  max-height: 240px; /* <-- This must be tweaked to fit the maximum content */
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.height0 {
  max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <span class="flip top-button" target="#first-div">Div1</span>
    <span class="flip top-button" target="#second-div">Div2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="first-div">
    <h1>I'm the first DIV</h1>
    <p>Some content of DIV 1 here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content height0" id="second-div">
    <h1>I'm the second DIV</h1>
    <p>Some content of DIV 2 here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!